# No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher

Tags: android, cordova, installation

I want to install Cordova and I got a error that cordova cannot find build tools.
I install android sdk 24 and set Android-Home, but error is remained.

How can i solve it?